# Creating a JSON structure out of HTML with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, json, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I am working with BeautifulSoup, trying to parse a simple HTML document that looks like this:

[image]

(Naturally, the structure continues on this basic manner a few levels deeper.  However, occasionally there is an extra bullet, which provides no information, thus I would like to ignore it.)

My goal is to parse this into JSON format.

I would like the end result look like:

```
{
    "Outer List": {
        "Inner List" : [
            "info 1", 
            "info 2", 
            "info 3"
        ]
    }
}
```

The code below (all thanks due @Zero Piraeus) comes very close to working:
[Parsing nested HTML list with BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17850121/parsing-nested-html-list-with-beautifulsoup)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pprint import pprint
soup = BeautifulSoup("""
   <html>
     <body>
      <ul class="rootList">
       <li class="liItem endPlus">
        <span class="itemToBeAdded">
         Outer List
        </span>
       </li>
       <li class="noBulletsLi ">
        <ul class="innerUl">
         <li class="liItem crossPlus">
          <span class="itemToBeAdded">
           Inner List
          </span>
          <ul class="grayStarUl ">
           <li class="">
            <span class="phrasesToBeAdded">
             info 1
            </span>
           </li>
           <li class="">
            <span class="phrasesToBeAdded">
             info 2
            </span>
           </li>
           <li class="">
            <span class="phrasesToBeAdded">
             info 3
            </span>
           </li>
          </ul>
         </li>
          </ul>
         </li>
        </ul>
     </body>
    </html>
""")

ul = soup.body.ul

def dictify(ul):
    result = {}
    for li in ul.find_all("li", recursive=False):
        list = []
        key = next(li.stripped_strings)
        ul = li.find("ul")
        if ul:
            result[key] = dictify(ul)
        else:
            result[key] = None
    return result
```

This bit of code returns:

```
{u'Inner List': {u'Inner List': {u'info 1': None,
                                 u'info 2': None,
                                 u'info 3': None}},
 u'Outer List': None}
```

Whereas I'm trying to reach:

```
{u'Outer List': {u'Inner List': [u'info 1',
                                  'info 2',
                                  'info 3']}
```

How can I get my `'info X'` items into a list as the value, in a hopefully reasonably scalable manner....and ignore those pesky bullets that may be present?

Thank you for reading this far!

Comment: Hope you are not going to delete the question again.

Comment: I know @alecxe, thanks for your comment last time. It inspired me to clean up my question!  :)

Comment: Object of type 'BeautifulSoup' is not JSON serializable

Answer (score 5):

Here's one way to do it:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """your html goes here""" 
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

inner_ul = soup.find('ul', class_='innerUl')
inner_items = [li.text.strip() for li in inner_ul.ul.find_all('li')]

outer_ul_text = soup.ul.span.text.strip()
inner_ul_text = inner_ul.span.text.strip()

result = {outer_ul_text: {inner_ul_text: inner_items}}
print result
```

prints:

```
{u'Outer List': {u'Inner List': [u'info 1', u'info 2', u'info 3']}}
```

Comment: This is fantastic!  I'm wondering, could it be generalized such that I could read in the same list, given it had more sublists?

Comment: You have to be more specific: sublist inside which list? Outer List or Inner List, etc?

Comment: Say, `info 2` had a sublist such that `info2_sublist_1`, `info2_sublist_2`, and `info2_sublist_3` were beneath it, in the HTML?  
Since this is JSON, wouldn't it be nice to end up with  `{u'Outer List': {u'Inner List': [u'info 1',{info 2: ['info2_sublist_1', 'info2_sublist_2','info2_sublist_3]}','info 3']}`?

Comment: OK guys, thanks for your help!  I asked a follow-up question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22672292/html-and-beautifulsoup-how-to-iteratively-parse-when-the-structure-is-not-alway