# HTML and BeautifulSoup: how to iteratively parse when the structure is not always known beforehand?

Tags: python, html, json, parsing, beautifulsoup

I began with a simple HTML structure, something like this:

[image]

Thanks to the help of @alecxe, I was able to create this JSON dict:

`{u'Outer List': {u'Inner List': [u'info 1', u'info 2', u'info 3']}}`

using his code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """your html goes here: see the very end of post""" 
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

inner_ul = soup.find('ul', class_='innerUl')
inner_items = [li.text.strip() for li in inner_ul.ul.find_all('li')]

outer_ul_text = soup.ul.span.text.strip()
inner_ul_text = inner_ul.span.text.strip()

result = {outer_ul_text: {inner_ul_text: inner_items}}
print result
```

The code is fantastic, and I've been trying to rewrite it in an iterable manner.

My 'real' HTML dataset is much larger and nastier, and I need to scale the code up in a way that I could handle something like this:

[image]

Or, maybe the data looks as such:

[image]

To make things even worse, perhaps underneath `sublist` we have yet another `sublist`!  Ultimately, this is my real situation.

My problem is this:  I can't find a way to generalize the aforementioned BeautifulSoup code to deal with either of the above situations (much less the 3rd 'even worse' scenario!).

How can I recursively / iteratively plumb the depths of my HTML, and extract the information, when I don't have access to the exact structure of the HTML beforehand?  Is this even possible with BeautifulSoup?  Surely there must be some way that I'm missing, to determine the depth first and then proceed.

Thanks a lot for making this far!

The HTML for the last example is here:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <ul class="rootList">
   <li class="liItem endPlus">
    <span class="itemToBeAdded">
     Outer List
    </span>
   </li>
   <li class="noBulletsLi ">
    <ul class="innerUl">
     <li class="liItem crossPlus">
      <span class="itemToBeAdded">
       Inner List
      </span>
      <ul class="grayStarUl ">
       <li class="">
        <span class="phrasesToBeAdded">
         info 1
        </span>
       </li>
       <li class="">
        <span class="phrasesToBeAdded">
         info 2
         </span>
       </li>
       <li class="">
        <span class="phrasesToBeAdded">
         info 3
        </span>
             <ul class="grayStarUl">
                 <li class="">
                     <span class="phrasesToBeAdded">sublist</span>
                 </li>
             </ul>            
       </li>
      </ul>
     </li>
      </ul>
     </li>
    </ul>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: See [this](http://www.xavierdupre.fr/blog/2013-10-27_nojs.html). I believe it's in Python 3.x, though.

Comment: Thanks! I have tried it and it doesn't work well for my particular problem, I'm afraid.  (yes it is for Python 3.x)

Comment: I'm unsure of what you are trying to achieve. As I understand it so far you want to extract info from all the <spans>? Is it important that you preserve the structure afterwards or is the data itself enough?

Comment: Just a question, Is the `<ul>` description always get from first `<li><span>` element ?

Answer (score 3):

You can write two parsers which recursively call each other:

```
def parse_list(tag):
    return map(parse_list_item, tag.find_all('li', recursive=False))

def parse_list_item(tag):
    text = tag.find(text=True, recursive=False).strip()
    text += '\n' + tag.span.text.strip() if tag.span.parent == tag else ''
    inner = tag.find('ul', recursive=False)
    if inner is None:  # no more nesting:
        return text.strip()
    else:  # more nesting
        return {text.strip():parse_list(inner)} if text else parse_list(inner)
```

Above does not utilize any `class` information, and should work regardless of depth of the inner lists:

```
>>> parse_list(soup.find('ul'))
[u'Outer List', [{u'Inner List': [u'info 1', u'info 2', {u'info 3': [u'sublist']}]}]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit unsure of what you are trying to achieve. So I'm going to presume that you want to extract data from all spans and don't care about the structure. If you explain more precisely what you want to achieve I'll update my answer.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)
spans = soup.findall(class="phrasesToBeAdded")
text = []
for element in spans:
    text.append(element.get_text())
```