# Retrieve Data from TOC

Tags: python

I aim to convert the TOC of [The Python Language Reference — Python 3.6.3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/index.html) to a structured data with the following steps:

1.copy contents to a `plr.md` file

```
In [1]: with open('plr.md') as file:
   ...:     content = file.read()
In [2]: content
Out[2]: '\n\n- \\1. Introduction\n  - [1.1. Alternate Implementations]
(https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/introduction.html#alternate-implementations)\n  - [1.2. Notation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/introduction.html#notation)\n- \\2. Lexical analysis\n  - [2.1. Line structure]
(https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/lexical_analysis.html#line-structure)\n  - [2.2. Other tokens](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/lexical_analysis.html#other-tokens)\n
```

2.Get chapters

```
In [47]: chapters = content.split('\n- \\')
    ...: #subtract the unqualified part
    ...: chapters = chapters[1:]
In [50]: chapters[0]
Out[50]: '1. Introduction\n  - [1.1. Alternate Implementations](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/introduction.html#alternate-implementations)
\n  - [1.2. Notation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/introduction.html#notation)'
```

3.Separate chapter name and section name in each chapters

```
chapter_details = chapters[0].split('\n  -')
sections = chapter_details[1:]
chapter = chapter_details[0]
In [54]: chapter
Out[54]: '1. Introduction'
In [55]: sections
Out[55]:
[' [1.1. Alternate Implementations](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/introduction.html#alternate-implementations)',
 ' [1.2. Notation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/introduction.html#notation)']
```

4.Convert section

```
def convert_section(s):
    start = s.index('[') + 1
    end = s.index(']')
    return s[start:end]
In [57]: print(convert_section(' [1.1. Alternate Implementations](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/i
    ...: ntroduction.html#alternate-implementations)'))
1.1. Alternate Implementations

sections = map(convert_section, sections)
sections = list(sections)
```

5.create a dict

```
key = chapter
{key:sections}
 {'1. Introduction':['1.1. Alternate Implementations', '1.2. Notation']}
```

6.encapsulate codes in a class and get the result

```
class TOC:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename

    def read(self, filename):
        with open (filename) as file:
            content = file.read()
        return content

    def convert_section(self, s):
        start = s.index('[') + 1
        end = s.index(']')
        return s[start:end]

    def get_chapters(self, filename):
        content = self.read(filename)
        chapters = content.split('\n- \\')
        #subtract the unqualified part
        chapters = chapters[1:]
        return chapters

    def create_chapter_dict(self, chapter):
        chapter_details = chapter.split('\n  -')
        sections = chapter_details[1:]
        key = chapter_details[0]
        value = map(self.convert_section, sections)
        return {key: list(value)}

    def get_chapters_dict(self):
        chapters = self.get_chapters(self.filename)
        chapters_dict = {}
        for chapter in chapters:
            chapter_dict = self.create_chapter_dict(chapter)
            chapters_dict.update(chapter_dict)
        return chapters_dict
```

Run and get the result

```
In [89]: TOC('plr.md').get_chapters_dict()
Out[89]:
{'1. Introduction': ['1.1. Alternate Implementations', '1.2. Notation'],
 '2. Lexical analysis': ['2.1. Line structure',
  '2.2. Other tokens',
  '2.3. Identifiers and keywords',
  '2.4. Literals',
  '2.5. Operators',
  '2.6. Delimiters'],
 '3. Data model': ['3.1. Objects, values and types',
  '3.2. The standard type hierarchy',
  '3.3. Special method names',
  '3.4. Coroutines'],
```

This solution is a bit too much for a daily common operation, is there a standard or easy method for such a task?

Comment: Since the source data already is structured as nested html lists I would use a parser capable of extracting information from html to solve the task. [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) should be a good fit.

Comment: This question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17850121/parsing-nested-html-list-with-beautifulsoup seems to do pretty much what you are looking for. If that is the case you might want to mark your question as a duplicate.